# how to restrict user from accessing another user's pages by inputing id in url laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a web app i'm working on.Users can create patients, which have a unique id. Problem I have is that when another user logs in, he can easily access patients not assigned to him by simply inputing their id in the url. Please how do i solve this? Heres a sample of my route for the 
user to view his patient:

`Route::get('patients/{patient}/view', 'Portal\PatientController@viewPatient');`

and in the Patientcontroller:

```
public function viewPatient($patient){
    $patient = Patient::where('id', $patient)->first();
    return view ('portal.patient',compact('patient'));
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#creating-policies) for that:

> Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a particular model or resource. For example, if your application is a blog, you may have a Post model and a corresponding  PostPolicy to authorize user actions such as creating or updating posts.

Or [gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates):

> Gates are Closures that determine if a user is authorized to perform a given action

I'd use policies, but you also can manually check if a user can view a page with something like:

```
if (auth()->id() !== $patient) {
    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'You can not view this page');
}
```

Comment: I think policies should do the magic. I'm reading up on it right now. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You could also keep `GET` to access to this page without inputing the `id`. For example, if you want to obtain patients only from the current user logged in :

**web.php** :

```
Route::get('patients/view', 'Portal\PatientController@viewPatient');
```

**Patientcontroller** :

```
public function viewPatient(){
    $id = auth()->id();

    $patient = Patient::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view ('portal.patient',compact('patient'));
}
```

Keep in mind that this will work only with an authenticated user.

Comment: This would work but I was passing the id in the url because I just want to view a particular patient. Your technique may not work if there's more than one patient

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you wanted to have access only to all the patients of a user

Answer (score 0):

If your database table structure is like this

```
Patients
--------
id //Unique ID of Patient
user_id //User that created
patient
```

Then you can do the check in controller like.

```
public function viewPatient($patient)
{
    $patient_check = Patient::where('id', $patient)->where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
    if($patient_check == null || count($patient_check) == 0)
    {
        return "You cannot view this patient";
    }
    else
    {
        return view ('portal.patient',compact('patient'));
    }
}
```

This is simple and yet does the work.

Comment: Yes, This actually does it. i just didn't like the logic of always defining it in every controller when I have to retrieve patients. Thanks @Ali

Comment: It does the work. You can create helper functions if you are not pro in laravel. Nvm. If it helps do mark it :)